# How do I get import the original value from XLSX using SheetJS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, xlsx, sheetjs

I am using Google Apps Script with SheetJS library to import table from XSLX file to my Google Sheet.

Here is the code fragment:

```
function IMPORTXLSX(url, sheetName, range) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new Error("XLSX file cannot be obtained. Please confirm the link again.");
  }
  const book = XLSX.read(new Uint8Array(res.getContent()), { type: "array" });
  const worksheet = book.Sheets[sheetName];
  if (!range) {
    const csv = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet);
    const values = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
    return values;
  }
  var rng = XLSX.utils.decode_range(range);
  const values = [];
  for (let row = rng.s.r; row <= rng.e.r; row++) {
    const temp = [];
    for (let col = rng.s.c; col <= rng.e.c; col++) {
      const v = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ r: row, c: col });
      temp.push(worksheet[v] ? worksheet[v].v : null);
    }
    values.push(temp);
  }
  return values;
}
```

And, just in case, the way I call the function:

```
function refreshFinexData() {
  console.log("Trying to update Finex data.");
  const url = "https://api.finex-etf.ru/v1/fonds/nav.xlsx";
  const sheetName = "Report";

  // Fetch and parse the XLSX data
  const data = IMPORTXLSX(url, sheetName);

  // Check if data is fetched successfully
  if (data) {
    // Calculate the number of rows and columns in the data
    const numRows = data.length;
    const numCols = data[0].length;

    // Clear the previous data in the destination range
    const outputRange = realPortfolioSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("techListFinexOutputRange");
    outputRange.clearContent();

    // Set the values in the destination range
    // Note: You must adjust the output range's size to match the number of rows in the fetched data
    const destinationRange = techListSheet.getRange(outputRange.getRow(), outputRange.getColumn(), numRows, numCols);
    destinationRange.setValues(data);
    console.log("The Finex data was updated successfully.");
  } else {
    throw new Error("Data could not be fetched. Please check the URL and try again.");
  }
}
```

The problem is - when is the original file the value is equal to "0,797698", when I open the original xlsx file it is being displayed as "0,80" (I can still see the original value, but only if I click on the cell directly). And "0.80" is being copied to my sheet. But I need the original value.

It seems that problem arised only few days ago - it is possible that something in original file format has changed leading to this issue, but I am not sure.

The exact value is still in the file, but now it seems that I am unable to retrieve it.

Can you help me retrieve the original data?

Thank you!

Tried changing

```
temp.push(worksheet[v] ? worksheet[v].v : null);
```

to

```
temp.push(cell ? cell.w : null);
```

No results.

Comment: You probably just need to change the format of the cell in Google sheets. Also, where is `XLSX` defined? If  you're using a library, provide it's Github link.

Comment: Hi!

There is no problem with Google Sheets cell format - by the moment value reaches it, it's already rounded. However, I bet if I change the format of the original cell in the source file (so it would not round it up for display) - that would solve the problem. Cannot do that, though. 

Regarding library - I am using SheetJS, here is the documentation https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/  and here is git https://git.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/sheetjs

Comment: How did you include sheetjs in apps script?

Comment: Added it as a file to the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tested your showing script, I noticed that when the values are retrieved as CSV data, it seems that the values are rounded. But, when I checked the options, I couldn't find the option for resolving it. So, as one direction, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the function `IMPORTXLSX` is modified.

```js
function IMPORTXLSX(url, sheetName, range) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new Error("XLSX file cannot be obtained. Please confirm the link again.");
  }
  const book = XLSX.read(new Uint8Array(res.getContent()), { type: "array" });
  const worksheet = book.Sheets[sheetName];
  if (!range) {
    const csv = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet);
    const ar = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
    range = XLSX.utils.encode_range({ s: { c: 0, r: 0 }, e: { c: ar[0].length - 1, r: ar.length - 1 } });
  }
  var rng = XLSX.utils.decode_range(range);
  const values = [];
  for (let row = rng.s.r; row <= rng.e.r; row++) {
    const temp = [];
    for (let col = rng.s.c; col <= rng.e.c; col++) {
      const v = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ r: row, c: col });
      temp.push(worksheet[v] ? worksheet[v].v : null);
    }
    values.push(temp);
  }
  return values;
}
```

- In the case of this modified script, the cell values are retrieved without rounding.
- In this modification, it supposes that sheetjs library has already been able to be used. Please be careful about this.