# Downloading an xlsx file from a webpage with google apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gsheets

The webpage already has the export xlsx option.
I would like to get the data from the page and paste it to a gsheet. Is it possible with a script? if yes, could you explain me the process a bit.

Thank you

[image: export option]

Comment: I thought that these threads might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76635370 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/75706380

Comment: I think that link in the example takes you directly to an xlsx file. it doesn't look like it would work for me. but thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful in your situation. About `it doesn't look like it would work for me.`, can I ask you about the detail of it?